# How would I automatically make models just by the information from uploading a CSV file in django? As opposed to manually making models in models.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Hello I would like to make an automatic model maker where it would parse through the csv file that is uploaded via form. It then would make a new model every time with their respective fields. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Models are supposed to be static. In case you want to store 2d data, you should *linearize* it, for example with a model with three columns: row, col, value.

Comment: you may be interested in: https://github.com/rvinzent/django-dynamic-models but read the disclaimer on their github page.